# Microsoft Graph Toolkit React: mgt-person how to access 'activity' value from presence data?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Is it possible using the mgt-person component to output the value of the presence activity string (e.g. "OnAcall") as one of the line property values?

Example below - see line2-property example:

```
<mgt-person person-query="someone@something.com" show-presence view="threelines" line1-property="displayName" line2-property="Presence.Activity???" person-card="hover"></mgt-person>
```

Comment: The mgt-person's `line1-property` only currently supports properties provided in the personDetails object. Presence isn't part of this unfortunately but I do think this is a great feature request, would you mind creating this issue on the [repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new/choose)?

We can facilitate the overall ask and discussion better there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Person showPresence personQuery="...">`